# Can't find Setter in MVVM

Tags: android, xml, mvvm, error-handling

I start to learn MVVM and I started with the below link

[MVVM](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/android-mvvm-design-pattern)

I've written everything that the site explained but when I run the program, I have the below error.

```
[databinding] {"msg":"Cannot find a setter for \u003candroid.widget.Button bind:toastMessage\u003e that accepts parameter type \u0027java.lang.String\u0027\n\nIf a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.","file":"app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\login.xml","pos":[{"line0":45,"col0":37,"line1":45,"col1":57}]}
```

I don't know where is my error and how I can solve it. I've searched a lot and I did clean and rebuild again or I catch and restart android studio but it didn't work. If you can please help me.
These are my codes:

User:

```
public class User {
private String emial;
private String password;

public User(String emial, String password) {
    this.emial = emial;
    this.password = password;
}

public void setEmial(String emial) {
    this.emial = emial;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmial() {
    return emial;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
}
```

LoginViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel extends BaseObservable {
private User user;
private String successMessage="Login was successful";
private String errorMessage="Email or Password not valid";

@Bindable
private String toastMessge=null;

public String getToastMessge(){
    return toastMessge;
}
private void setToastMessge(String toastMessge){
    this.toastMessge=toastMessge;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.toastMessge);
}

public void setUserEmail(String email){
    user.setEmial(email);
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.userEmail);
}

@Bindable
public String getUserEmail(){
    return user.getEmial();
}
@Bindable
public String getUserPassword(){
    return user.getPassword();
}

public void setUserPassword(String password){
    user.setPassword(password);
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.userPassword);
}

public LoginViewModel(){
    user=new User("","");
}

public void onLoginClicked(){
    if(isInputDataValid()){
        setToastMessge(successMessage);
    }else
        setToastMessge(errorMessage);
}

public boolean isInputDataValid(){
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(getUserEmail())&& Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(getUserEmail()).matches()&&getUserPassword().length()>5;
}
}
```

Login:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LoginBinding activityMainBinding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.login);


}
}
```

login.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.kit.mvvmtest.ViewModel.LoginViewModel" />
</data>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@={viewModel.userEmail}" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@={viewModel.userPassword}" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:onClick="@{()-> viewModel.onLoginClicked()}"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            bind:toastMessage="@{viewModel.toastMessge}" />


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you have not crated BindingAdapter in your Login Activity?

Comment: @AdityaNandardhane No, I didn't know that I have to add this. Now I added but I still have problem. The error is :   'error: cannot find symbol
import com.kit.mvvmtest.ViewModel;' from the below part:    ` public LoginViewModel(){
        user=new User("","");
    } `

Comment: Please add this as well  activityMainBinding.setViewModel(new LoginViewModel());
        activityMainBinding.executePendingBindings();

Comment: you have not intialize viewmodel in your activity

Answer (score 0):

```
setToastMessge()
```

in your LoginViewModel is **private**.